# Desire2Learn Valence API | JSON not loading

Tags: desire2learn

I'm using the Python Requests library with the Valence-provided Python SDK to attempt to do a GET request. Something odd is happening with the URL and I'm not sure what. The response I get is 200 (which leads me to believe that the authentication is working), but when I try to print the JSON from the Request object, it instead prints the HTML of the page instead of the JSON.

I'm using modified code that I read from http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/clients/python/auth.html.

Here's the Python code:

```
import requests
import auth as d2lauth
from auth import *

app_creds = { 'app_id': '----', 'app_key': '----' }

ac = d2lauth.fashion_app_context(app_id=app_creds['app_id'], app_key=app_creds['app_key'])

auth_url = ac.create_url_for_authentication('ugatest2.view.usg.edu', 'http://localhost:8080')

redirect_url = "https://localhost:8080?x_a=3----&x_b=3dMRgCBAHXJDTA2E6DJIfdWq-gYl-pk77fF_3X5oDUuqc"

uc = ac.create_user_context(auth_url, 'ugatest2.view.usg.edu', True)

route = 'ugatest2.view.usg.edu/d2l/api/versions/'

url = uc.create_authenticated_url(route)

r = requests.get(url)

print(r.text)
```

The output is the HTML of a page instead of JSON. If I do print(r), I get a status of 200. I think my redirect URL may be the issue, but I'm not sure what exactly is wrong. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Two things look off to me:

- Using `auth_url` to create a user context isn't going to work, that's the URL you need to send the user to so they can authenticate. You need to use the URL you were redirected to after authenticating to build the user context. Assuming `redirect_url` is that URL, you should be passing that to `create_user_context` and not `auth_url`.
- `ugatest2.view.usg.edu/d2l/api/versions/` is not a valid value for passing to `create_authenticated_route`, `/d2l/api/versions` is probably what you want. The SDK will prepend the scheme, domain, and port so including those in the value passed is going to result in an incorrect URI.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So the redirect URL is where I'm having issues, then. When I plug the auth_url into the browser and hit enter, it takes me to the login page for ugatest2. The URL does change, and I've plugged that in as the redirect_url. I notice my redirect_url isn't localhost like shown in the example. When I use that as the redirect_url, I get
**uID = parsed_query[self.CALLBACK_USER_ID][0]
KeyError: 'x_a'** when I run the program. Should I log into the ugatest2 and use _that_ URL instead?

Comment: You need to use the URL that gets redirected to after the user has completed logging in (e.g., if your web app is running at `https://app.some_domain.com/launch`, then your `redirect_url` should look something like `https://app.some_domain.com/launch?x_a=abcd&x_b=efgh`). If you're running this as a console app, you're probably going to want to spin up a short-lived http server to collect login credentials (that'll become your target) or get your user keypair out of band and hardcode them or provide them as arguments or environment variables.

Comment: The imports look a little off as well; typically you'd use "import d2lvalence.auth as d2lauth" to employ an absolute import reference; and, you shouldn't need to import * from the module -- probably best to just use the factory method to build the app context and the methods on the app and user contexts to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Once your app is working properly, you'll be able to access a JSON response by using `r.json()` rather than `r.text`.